# How to active sidebar menu link

Tags: wordpress

I am working on WordPress sidebar menu, I want to get link active when click on that particular link.

```
<ul id="menu-home" class="menu">
    <li id="menu-item-10" 
        class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home menu-item-10">
        <a href="page.php">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-50" 
        class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-50">
        <a href="page1.php">About</a>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-48" 
        class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-48">
        <a href="page2.php">Services</a>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-47" 
        class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-47">
        <a href="page3.php">Gallery</a>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-49" 
        class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-49">
        <a href="page4.php">Contact</a>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-235" 
        class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-235">
        <a href="page5.php">Blog</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add following CSS

```
.current_page_item {
color: #920606
}
```

Change hexadecimal code based on your design